# What file enforcement should be set on file upload for best user experience?

Tags: image, files, image-format, file-extension

We make website and we want our users to do things as they are supposed to.
But it's not like everyone knows everythings...

I'm creating a website ashiane.house that suppose to allow user to share their property information with other, in term of Selling, Renting, etc...

As we all knows these kind of websites, do not have a specific operator, and all kinds of user work with them, from professionals to people who may only use the computer for only necessity.

So is it good to enforce Specific image type? what type of image other than JPEG should we allow? what's the minimum file size that we should allow our users? do typical users knows how to decrease image size?

Answer (score 4):

If your application has limitations to file sizes and formats, then yes these should be conveyed to the users so that they can have a successful image upload.

Generally accepted formats are JPG and PNG. Most mobile phones and webcams produce images in these formats. As such it is necessary to support at least these two. Display these formats upfront in the uploader so that users understand.

What sort of size is needed – that depends on your application purposes. For displaying property images, a very large size is not really necessary. A gallery image size of about 600px X 600px @96dpi should suffice (talking about the minimum, says someone who works with professional property images all the time). You can vary and check if users complain about low quality images to figure out what is the acceptable minimum.

No, typical users do not know how to use special softwares to resize images, neither are they willing to do it. It will be best to have crop functionality built in your image uploader. Once the user adjusts the best part of the image to be displayed. The frame can be automatically resized to upload limits.

Comment: What image size do new phones produce? cause it's hard to tell someone who knows nothing, that they need to decrease file size or quality to match website requirement. But you see i have both space limitations on my server and a limit budget...

Comment: iPhone X (original image): 4032x3024 @72dpi, file size 2.2 MB.
I think you will have to put a limit around 5MB or 8MB to be on the safer side (for mobile phones only). Even the most basic point-and-shoot cameras produce images larger than 4000x4000. So camera image sizes will be definitely higher.

Comment: Since the project is on budget it will not be possible to process the uploaded image. Otherwise, the original image can be processed to acceptable limits before saving, and the original file retained or discarded. However, this will slow down the upload process. Alternatively, let the file be uploaded temporarily, create resized and lower resolution copy, and then delete the original to save space.

Comment: i do this process later, but i'm wonder how other people manage it, i made a temp directory, allowed 10MB + 1000 for unknown character in headers.
after user done, and save data, i upload it on database and coudinary... if project succeed i pay for months, otherwise if it reach the deadend (maximum usage) i just cut the service. the issue is, the server, server is 100Gig storage, 50Gig consumed, and the other if someone want to flood it... im wonder... i never face an attack before. but i gotta keep user action at minimum, but since i let them to store their own data too, no strict time limit

Comment: So i'm looking for best size to upload ... then i try to reduce the size... also provide caches and etc...
keeping track of temp data is gonna be hard too, i'm not sure...